# How to find Dependent Rowset in ZF2

Tags: validation, zend-framework2

I have two tables (just an example): `Cars` and `Colors`.

One `Car` have a `Color`, so I can't delete the color red if exists a car who is red. Easy.

With ZF1 I could verify easily this dependency before delete a color, by using `findDependentRowset()` method.

But how can I do this in ZF2?

It's a bad practice if I just let the delete method fail and than grab the exception and print a message?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct implementation of `findDependantRowset()` anymore in ZF2. ZF2 went back a step of providing a full ORM and instead simply provided functionality for easier Query-Management.

And exactly this would be your approach. You'd either do two queries `Query for CAR` then `Query Colords for CarColor` or you'd do a single query, where you query for both simultaneously. The later one being the faster approach, the first one being pretty much what `findDependantRowset()` did.

If you want more 'magic'-functionality, you'd be best advised to check out one of the many good ORMs out there. Doctrine 2 for example has a pretty neat ZF2 implementation already and appears to be a community standard as far as ZF2 is concerned. You may want to check out https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule

Comment: Perfect! I decide learn about ZF2 tableGateway before start using Doctrine 2, 'cause I still studing the new ZF version. But certainly I'll use Doctrine 2 in my next project. =) Thank for the help Sam!